# Does Chromium have "Federated Learning of Cohorts" (FLoC)?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, privacy

Google has introduced [FLoC](https://blog.google/products/ads-commerce/2021-01-privacy-sandbox/):

> Federated Learning of Cohorts (FLoC) proposes a new way for businesses to reach people with relevant content and ads by clustering large groups of people with similar interests. This approach effectively hides individuals “in the crowd” and uses on-device processing to keep a person’s web history private on the browser.

This has been released to customers right now, [according to this website](https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc):

> Google has launched trials of FLoC in Chrome browser version 89 on March 30th, 2021 in the USA, Canada, Australia, Brazil, Japan and several other countries for millions of users. FLoC is a part of the Chrome browser’s source code and it helps them do cookie-less and consent-less ad targeting.

From reading about FLoC it's clear it's part of the **Google Chrome browser**, but I can't figure out if it's also part of **Chromium**, the underlying open-source browser project?

This isn't to start a FLoC war or discuss the pros and cons of the technology, I just want to understand where exactly it fits into the technology stack to understand when and where I might encounter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find FLoC code in Chromium here: source.chromium.org/search?q=floc

To try FLoC in Chromium, download Chromium... [chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium](https://chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)

...then run it with flags as per the instructions at [floc.glitch.me](https://floc.glitch.me).

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking also about this and didn't found something straight ahead.
Here is a potential answer for this question:

http://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-privacy/privacy-sandbox/floc